# Recover commitment bond in smart optimistic rollup

Tags: smart-rollup

I did:

1. run a smart optimistic rollup on a testnet
2. stopped the rollup after some time and deleted all data including the kernel.

Now, i recognized that the 10'000tez bond is still locked on the corresponding operator implicit account.

How can I unlock/recover this commitment bond?

Note: I tried already using "octez-client recover bond ...", but this throws: "Attempted to withdraw while not staked on the last cemented commitment or its ancestor."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before being able to retrieve your bond you must not be staked anymore on any commitment for that rollup.

You are staked on a commitment until it's cemented, so you need to cement all commitment before submiting the `recover_bond` operation.

There is a delay you must respect before cementing a commitment.

The rollup node has a `bailout` mode that automate that, first it cement commitment when possible the recover your bond and exit.

Comment: Thanks. 

I deleted my (upgraded) kernel. How can I run the rollup in bailout mode without having the (upgraded) kernel? 

Hmm, what I am missing here?

Comment: If you can't rebuild your kernel and its upgrade then you can do manually the equivalent of the bailout mode. for each commit you have published starting from the oldest you can cement it using the `cement_commitment` operation. There is a command of the `octez-client` to do so. You might have to wait for some until the `challenge_window` is over for that commit.


When you are cemented all the commitment you have published, then you can submit the `recover_bond` operation.

Comment: Many thanks! This answered by question.